# How can I make sure program A quits/can not be started if program B is started/is tried started?

Tags: windows-7, windows, script

I want to be sure that a program A can not run at the same time as program B as they can interfere with each other.

I would preferably make a windows script that I can automatically launch at system start-up and that constantly monitor application A and B.

Has anyone done or know how to do this?

(I do have programming skills and know several programming languages, but not so much on Windows specific things like this)

I would need:
1. A way to check if a program is running.
2. To be able to close a program gently. And if it has not closed within a time limit I want to force it to quit.

Comment: You need to tell us more about these 2 programs. Are they started by a user or an event, and what is the general idea of these programs? Are they scripts/tools that are installed, or custom made? Can you provide a launcher for them that you program?

Comment: @LPChip: They are started by the user (e.g. notepad.exe and iexplorer.exe). I think I have found the solution, but I have to get to bed so I have to try it tomorrow.

Comment: You might consider using the Windows tool TASKLIST to check if a given program is running. See a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script